# What is the optimum programming environment for vb.net?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am currently using the following development tools and with certain mentioned versions.
Visual Studio 2008,
.NetFramework2,
Crystal Reports 2008,
Sql Server 2005,
MS Access 2003,

But these seem to be very old in timeline, we have these latest versions :

For Visual Studio =  VS10,VS11,VS12

For Framework = 3,3.5,4,4.5,4.51

For Crytal Reports : CrystalReports for VS10

For SQL : 2008,2012

For Access : 2007, 2010

And so much more..Just want to upgrade my tools. I want to know which is the best combination of versions that suits almost all client environments or is easy to implement. Do share your experiences also. Also suggest some new tools i should try out. It would really help. Thanks :)

Comment: Just use the latest versions.

Comment: Some people would say that "optimum programming environment for vb.net?" is an oxymoron !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the following combinations and i feel currently they are the most optimum combinations : VS10, .Net35, CR10, SQLServer2008, Access2007

Upgrading to the latest versions is not that healthy. It creates so much trouble while implementing on variety of OS.